# Laravel: Comparing Dates

Tags: laravel

Is there a better way of comparing dates than this? Seems clunky...

```
if(Carbon::parse($member->cancel_at)->toDateString() == Carbon::today()->toDateString())
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Check out: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you could try `isToday()` method:

```
$canceled = Carbon::parse($member->cancel_at);

if ($canceled->isToday()) {
    ....
```

You can make it shorter if you'll set `cancel_at` as [instance of Carbon with `$dates` array](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators). Then you'll be able to use just:

```
if ($member->cancel_at->isToday())
```

Comment: Great, getting warmer! However, I'm looking for a one-line solution. I was able to take what you did and convert it to this: `if(Carbon::parse($member->cancel_at)->isToday())` which works and is cleaner. See any issues with it?

Comment: I mutated `cancel_at` and used your updated example but it returned this `Call to a member function isToday() on null`. I guess I can't have `NULL` values for `created_at`?

Comment: @timgavin, how did you define `cancel_at` in migration? Do you create it with Carbon, like `$model->cancel_at = Carbon::now();` or something?

Comment: `$table->datetime('cancel_at')->nullable();`

Comment: You also need to add it to your `$dates` array on your model so Eloquent knows to return it as an instance of `Carbon`.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Comment: I have. This is in my model. `protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'cancel_at'];` Like I said, it works if `cancel_at` isn't `NULL`.

Comment: Regardless, you gave me two good solutions and answered my question. Thanks. :)